# Login loop / Intel Expired key - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics, lightdm

I'm stuck in a login loop with my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and LightDM. And to be honest, I'm pretty new in Unix.

I have tried many solutions found here like removing the .Xauthority file, creating a new root user, editing the lightdm.conf file, it did not work.

So I tried to update my drivers and I got this error (trying to translate it in English, sorry) :

> GPG Error, https://download.01.org trusty InRelease : Following
>   signatures are not valid : KEYEXPIRED [...]

When I hit the "apt-key list" command, I noticed that my Intel key was expired.

Obviously, I couldn't update it the classic way, so I've checked on Internet some other ways, and I've found these commands :

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \ sudo apt-key add -
```

But it does not work, I had :

> Unable to write in "-" (Success)

And as I said I'm a newbie, so I could not fix this by myself. I just tried to launch the first part of the command, and it works (I got a key), but actually I don't know where does the "-" command writes and reads... !

I've found other fixes for the drivers, like editing the file

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list

But what it contains does not fit with what I've read on Internet :

> deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main trusty main #Intel Graphics Drivers

As a desperate try, I've tried to install GNOME DESKTOP to replace LightDM :

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

But I got these errors (sorry for the translation again...) :

> addgroup : No GID is available in the range 100-999 (FIRST_SYS_GID - LAST_SYS_GID)
>
> addgroup : Le group "gdm" has not been created.
>
> dpkg: processing error for the "gdm" package (--configure)
>
> > the sub-processus script post-installation installed returned an error with state output 1
>
> dpkg: dependencies issues prevent the ubuntu-gnome-desktop configuration :
>
> > ubuntu-gnome-desktop depends on gdm; but :
> >     The gdm package is not configured yet.

And so on...

Can you see anything behind all of this in all this mess ?

Thank you for your help, I'm available if you need any information !

Comment: If i can't login via a gui; the first thing I do is switch to [text] terminal & login there, and check I have some disk space. A gui or graphical-desktop login will require the creation of work files which are stored in $HOME (your user directory), if there in insufficient space in $HOME (/home/$USER/ directory) the creation of work files fails & you are logged out (ie. login loop).  Create space & fix.  Also please note Ubuntu 14.04 (2014-April release, releases being *yy.mm* in format) came with 5 years of free support; and has already switched to ESM (paid support) as it's EOL end-of-month.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for replying :) But it is not a matter of size I guess, since with the df -h command I checked and my hard drives are maximum 5% used...

Comment: We could have researched more if you'd provided the actual key (google only this month let a key expire due oversight (google chrome/earth/.. couldn't update); in google's case they had it corrected in a few days).   As for space, it must have space in $HOME as space available elsewhere is of no use (gui login will fail).

Comment: Hello, the expired key is "2048R/75E52366 Rodrigo Vivi (Intel Linux Graphics) <rodrigo.vivi@intel.com>. When trying to update, the KEYEXPIRED is 1519672047.  How do you know if the home folder is full ? There is one user at 22G the other one at 4G and none of them is accessible ... Thanks for your answers !

Comment: `df -hl` will show disk free (human format, local drives only) where you look at /home/user/ or $USER to see space is available, and `df -ihl` to add --inodes to check inodes aren't used up.  Your issue doesn't sound like space; but 14.04 LTS is EOL end-today; so I doubt the key will be renewed unless it's used by later releases as well.   If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM, your Advantage support can be used now, so I'd use that; otherwise I'd remove the source, `sudo apt update` & look at release-upgrading to a supported release because of 14.04 LTS' EOL end-today.

Comment: Hello, Thanks again for your reply ! I'm going to updrade so, it seems simpler ! Do you think that I must make a backup on an external hard Drive or something ?

Comment: Yes you should always do a backup, especially of data that is valuable to you. Should you expect to need the backup? No most likely you won't, but power outage, or other can always occur so problems can occur. This may be helpful - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#0  (there are many blogs about this, I prefer official documentation, and if you prefer commands with less walk-thru https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html).

Comment: Just fyi:  over the weekend I upgraded a Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (flavors have only 3 years of support so the LXDE components were EOL even if parts still had 2 years remaining of support).  My old box had issues with the release-upgrade; so I just wrote 18.04 LTS [ISO] to thumb-drive; and re-installed (using *something-else*, overwrite but *no format*) and the box is back to operational (but 18.04 LTS instead of 16.04 LTS).

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you so much, I wanted to avoid upgrade / reset because I have no external hard drive for this but I think I'll need to buy one ! Thanks a lot m'y Friend for your help, I owe you one !